How to fix broken/cracked fence post?
During a storm last week, my neighbor's fence broke and fell. I was checking my fence to avoid that in the near future, and I found that one of the posts is cracked across the width close to the ground (orange box in the picture). These are 4x4 posts. If I push on the post, it moves. It is probably only one strong storm away from breaking away and taking my fence down. Is there any way to fix this and keep my fence standing? One obvious solution is to dig up this post and replace it with a new one, but is there any other easier solution that involves just fixing this post?


Is the wood post set in concete?

With the lack of length at the bottom, steel angle pieces might be best.
Screws plus fencing wire wrap around the angle iron should work.
The deeper you can drive the angle iron into the ground, the better.  Two or three feet on each side of the crack.
